# How do you transfer all your connection configuration from one RapidSQL install to another?

Tags: sql, database, rapidsql

Has anyone encountered this problem? I have installed RapidSQL on a new team member's machine, and now I want to configure his installation with my connection configuration (20+ connections). Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a file RapidSQL uses to transfer this information?

Thanks for any feedback.